# Launch MPC from c# with ProcessStartInfo wont work with Args

Tags: c#

I run Media Player Classic from C#. If i use this to start a specific position in the player the dynamic way will not work, the hardcoded will. Can anyone tell me how to get it to work the dynamic way?

```
// sPlayerExe: C:\Program Files\MPC-BE x64\mpc-be64.exe
// vidFile:    "E:\TV\Konzerte, Shows\Seer - Open Air in Grundlsee 2014.mp4"
// startPos:   /startpos 01:14:10

ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = sPlayerExe,  
    Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}\" /startpos {1}", vidFile, startPos)  // dont work
    //Arguments = "\"E:\\TV\\Konzerte, Shows\\Seer - Open Air in Grundlsee 2014.mp4\" /startpos 01:14:10"  // work
};
```

If i build the Args (last code line) manually the player will start correctly, but if is use the first Arguments somehow the MPC always starts at the beginning of the videofile, so it seems to dont understand the Args build by C#.

Run it on win command line this way works also correct:

```
"C:\Program Files\MPC-BE x64\mpc-be64.exe" "E:\TV\Konzerte, Shows\Seer - Open Air in Grundlsee 2014.mp4" /startpos 01:14:10
```

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Here is some copied debugged code.. only the last (manually) args string works correctly.

```
Debug.Write(sVidFile);   // E:\TV\Konzerte, Shows\Seer - Open Air in Grundlsee 2014.mp4
Debug.Write(sStartPos);  // 01:14:10

// args = string.Format("\"{0}\" /startpos {1}", sVidFile, sStartPos);
// args = "\"" + sVidFile + "\"" + " /startpos " + sStartPos;

args = "\"E:\\TV\\Konzerte, Shows\\Seer - Open Air in Grundlsee 2014.mp4\" /startpos 01:14:10";
```

Comment: Is `startPos` actually `startPos:   /startpos 01:14:10`? Because that would yield `"{0}" /startpos /startpos 01:14:10`. I would recommend you to create a variable outside and do there the formatting, you'll be able to see what's wrong

Comment: startpos contains /startpos 01:14:10

Arguments as Var will be:
    "E:\TV\Konzerte, Shows\Seer - Open Air in Grundlsee 2014.mp4" /startpos 01:14:10

Comment: So you end up generating `/startpos /startpos`... Remove one of those

Comment: No, it ended up this way:
`string args = "\"" + sVidFile + "\"" + " /startpos " + sStartPos;`
`Dbg(args);`
`// "E:\TV\Konzerte, Shows\Seer - Open Air in Grundlsee 2014.mp4" /startpos 01:14:10`

Comment: Please see the edit in post above. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it... there is an "\n" in the end oft the sStartPos, a .Trim() does it to work correct.